# How to set Google Sitelinks?

Tags: google, sitelinks

How can I get google to recognize my different pages of my website?

Example: [image: example]

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my site-map, but how would I create one so that I could name each of those pages?

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is "[Google Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)"

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to
>   the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms
>   to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your
>   site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.
>
> At the moment, sitelinks are automated. We're always working to
>   improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster
>   input in the future. There are best practices you can follow, however,
>   to improve the quality of your sitelinks. For example, for your site's
>   internal links, make sure you use anchor text and alt text that's
>   informative, compact, and avoids repetition.
>
> If you think that a sitelink URL is inappropriate or incorrect, you
>   can demote it. Demoting a URL for a sitelink tells Google that you
>   don't consider this URL a good sitelink candidate for a specific page
>   on your site. Google doesn't guarantee that demoted URLs will never
>   appear as a sitelink, but we do consider a demotion a strong hint that
>   we'll try to honor when generating sitelinks.